# Android app working smoothly in Samsung but not working in Huawei phones

Tags: android, android-studio, samsung-mobile, huawei-mobile-services

I have an Andriod application which is working perfectly fine in Samsung phones but is very slow in phones like Huawei. It's very slow and after some time it crashes.

The most common error in my logcat is:

- E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 1149 ms
- E/LocationManager: dead callback, clear wakeLock
- ZrHungImpl:  sendAppFreezeEvent failed!

My build type in manifest is:
 buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled true

```
        shrinkResources true

        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
    }
}
```

Dependencies are

dependencies {

```
implementation fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.preference:preference:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.googlecode.json-simple:json-simple:1.1'
implementation 'com.github.hotchemi:permissionsdispatcher:4.5.0'
implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:1.0.1'
implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
annotationProcessor 'com.google.auto.value:auto-value:1.5.2'
implementation 'com.facebook.network.connectionclass:connectionclass:1.0.1'
implementation 'fr.bmartel:jspeedtest:1.31.3'

//QR-Code
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:19.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.zxing:core:3.3.0'
implementation 'me.dm7.barcodescanner:zxing:1.9'
//to implement vertical expansion on floating action bar
implementation 'com.getbase:floatingactionbutton:1.10.1'
//    implementation "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpcore:4.4.1"
//     compile "org.apache.httpcomponents:httpmime:4.3"
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
//For Google API location
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:17.0.0'
//compile 'com.android.support:support-annotations:27.0.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:17.0.0'
// RecyclerView
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.1.0'
// CardView
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
//Progress-Bar
implementation 'com.github.d-max:spots-dialog:0.7@aar'

//OkHttp
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:mockwebserver:3.11.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.9.0'
//Retrofit
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.4.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-scalars:2.1.0'
implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.4.0'
//Logging
implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:3.9.0'

// Bottom Navigational Bar
implementation 'com.aurelhubert:ahbottomnavigation:2.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.gridlayout:gridlayout:1.0.0'

// Firebase Crashlytics SDK
implementation 'com.crashlytics.sdk.android:crashlytics:2.10.1'
//Firebase SDK
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:17.2.2'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.0'
// Admin SDK

//Shortcut badger - balloon notification
implementation "me.leolin:ShortcutBadger:1.1.22@aar"

//AVLoadingIndicatorView Animation
implementation 'com.wang.avi:library:2.1.3'

// Fabric answers
implementation('com.crashlytics.sdk.android:answers:1.4.7@aar') {
    transitive = true
}

// Calendar API URL: https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView
implementation 'com.github.sundeepk:compact-calendar-view:3.0.0'

// In-app update
//http://revisitingandroid.blogspot.com/2016/12/programmatically-check-play-store-for.html
implementation 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.12.1'
implementation 'com.google.android.play:core:1.6.4'


// Android architecture components
// Room components
implementation "androidx.room:room-runtime:$rootProject.roomVersion"
annotationProcessor "androidx.room:room-compiler:$rootProject.roomVersion"
androidTestImplementation "androidx.room:room-testing:$rootProject.roomVersion"

// Lifecycle components
implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"
implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:viewmodel:1.1.1"
annotationProcessor "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$rootProject.archLifecycleVersion"

// UI
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:$rootProject.materialVersion"

// Testing
androidTestImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$rootProject.coreTestingVersion"

// Modbus Library
implementation files('libs/modbus4Android-1.2.jar')
//implementation 'com.infiniteautomation:modbus4j:3.0.3'
```

}

Logcat:

```
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25896368
    I/NetworkSchedulerService: onStartCommand
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e00294010 disconnect failed
    D/ViewRootImpl[ApplicationSettings]: surface should not be released
    D/ActivityThread: Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{f6dd67a token=android.os.BinderProxy@a2fb554 {**.***.****/**.***.****.settings.ApplicationSettings}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@a2fb554
    D/ActivityThread: Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{457e195 token=android.os.BinderProxy@aca1f82 {**.***.****/**.***.****.commonData.LoginActivity}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@aca1f82
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: stop checker.
    V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 857
    V/FA: Activity paused, time: 25897224
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25897236
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e13a1f010 disconnect failed
    D/ViewRootImpl[MainMenu]: surface should not be released
    D/ActivityThread: Remove activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{4991fca token=android.os.BinderProxy@661e1fa {**.***.****/**.***.****.commonData.MainMenu}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@661e1fa
    W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
    V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: stop checker.
    V/FA: Screen exposed for less than 1000 ms. Event not sent. time: 790
    V/FA: Activity paused, time: 25898025
    W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@5995a94
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/ActivityThread: Skipping new config:{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:4 s.11}, config:{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:4 s.11} for app:**.***.****
    E/CursorResourceWrapper: context is wrong!
    V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
    V/FA: onActivityCreatedt.
    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25898239
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=2, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    I/NetworkSchedulerService: onStopJob
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    I/NetworkSchedulerService: onStartCommand
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e00294010 disconnect failed
    D/ViewRootImpl[MainActivity]: surface should not be released
    I/NetworkSchedulerService: onStartJob**.***.****.services.internetStateChange.ConnectivityReceiver@e571a8c
    I/pumps.caretake: Waiting for a blocking GC ProfileSaver
    I/pumps.caretake: Background concurrent copying GC freed 110663(4MB) AllocSpace objects, 40(2MB) LOS objects, 50% free, 5MB/11MB, paused 268us total 121.081ms
    I/pumps.caretake: WaitForGcToComplete blocked ProfileSaver on HeapTrim for 117.801ms
    W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e0352a010 disconnect failed
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
    V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
    W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
    V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: stop checker.
    V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 5670
    V/FA: Connecting to remote service
    V/FA: Activity paused, time: 25903905
    W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@3d07ebe
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/ActivityThread: Skipping new config:{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:4 s.11}, config:{1.0 ?mcc?mnc [en_GB] ldltr sw360dp w360dp h679dp 480dpi nrml long hdr port finger -keyb/v/h -nav/h winConfig={ mBounds=Rect(0, 0 - 1080, 2037) mAppBounds=Rect(0, 81 - 1080, 2118) mWindowingMode=fullscreen mActivityType=undefined} nonFullScreen=0 suim:4 s.11} for app:**.***.****
    V/ActivityThread: callActivityOnCreate
    V/FA: onActivityCreated
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=0, mNavBarShow=false, mIsFloating=false
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor true mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=false, mIsFloating=false
    V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    I/Window: window add KeepScreenOnFlag for **.***.****
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor true mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=true
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@1c10fec,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@8be9b45
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@2a53ed8,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@8be9b45
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@68f506d,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@8be9b45
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@75d8669,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@8be9b45
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{7ca25fa token=android.os.BinderProxy@3d07ebe {**.***.****/**.***.****.settings.ApplicationSettings}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@3d07ebe
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25904022
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=2, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    V/FA: Connection attempt already in progress
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    D/FA: Connected to remote service
    V/FA: Processing queued up service tasks: 4
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e00216010 disconnect failed
    D/ViewRootImpl[MainMenu]: surface should not be released
    W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
    V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e003ff010 disconnect failed
    D/OpenGLRenderer: endAllActiveAnimators on 0x7e01584d00 (RippleDrawable) with handle 0x7e00281480
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
    W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
    V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: stop checker.
    V/FA: Recording user engagement, ms: 1479
    W/ActivityThread: handleWindowVisibility: no activity for token android.os.BinderProxy@da39505
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor true mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=false, mIsFloating=false
    D/ActivityThread: add activity client record, r= ActivityRecord{993ea8a token=android.os.BinderProxy@da39505 {**.***.****/**.***.****.settings.RegisteringDevice}} token= android.os.BinderProxy@da39505
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: notify runnable to start.
    V/FA: Activity resumed, time: 25905580
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=1, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    I/HwPhoneWindow: updateLayoutParamsColor false mSpecialSet=false, mForcedNavigationBarColor=false, navigationBarColor=ff000000, mNavBarShow=true, mIsFloating=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 1
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e0143a010 disconnect failed
    D/ViewRootImpl[ApplicationSettings]: surface should not be released
    W/Settings: Setting device_provisioned has moved from android.provider.Settings.Secure to android.provider.Settings.Global.
    V/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: User setup is finished.
    D/HwAutofillHelper: recordCurrentInfo:0
    D/HwAutofillHelper: inputType = 97
    W/InputMethodManager: startInputReason = 4
    I/InputMethodManager: showSoftInput
    I/InputMethodManager: mServedView =**.***.****;view =**.***.****;flags =0
    I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
    E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    E/SpannableStringBuilder: SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE spans cannot have a zero length
    V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
    W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    W/System: A resource failed to call close. 
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 244 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: message delay warning
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: message delay warning
    D/ZrHung.AppEyeUiProbe: message delay warning
    E/ZrHungImpl:  sendAppFreezeEvent failed!
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 405 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@88332c3,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@f263740
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@8d7876c,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@f263740
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@d6bae58,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@f263740
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    I/HwSecImmHelper: mSecurityInputMethodService is null
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 1012 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=2, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    W/pumps.caretake: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->get()Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard; (light greylist, reflection)
    W/pumps.caretake: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->open(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
    W/pumps.caretake: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/CloseGuard;->warnIfOpen()V (light greylist, reflection)
    W/pumps.caretake: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->setAlpnProtocols([B)V (light greylist, reflection)
    W/pumps.caretake: Accessing hidden method Lcom/android/org/conscrypt/OpenSSLSocketImpl;->getAlpnSelectedProtocol()[B (light greylist, reflection)
    D/OkHttp: <-- 200 OK https://******.com/****I/api/device/details/12345678 (149ms)
    D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
    D/OkHttp: [{"DeviceSerialNumber":"321","Allocated":"","ProductID":"1"}]
    D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (201-byte body)
    V/AudioManager: playSoundEffect   effectType: 0
    V/AudioManager: querySoundEffectsEnabled...
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@3ec14ac,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@7b07080
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@419157b,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@7b07080
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    I/FLTAG_FM: loadFeature class:com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    I/FLTAG_SFM: getRequireClassLoader() succ ! className: com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() : com.huawei.featurelayer.systemfeature.HwWidget.IHwSplineOverScrollerEx
    D/FeatureFactory: loadFeature() new IHwSplineOverScrollerEx()
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl paras: android.widget.OverScroller$SplineOverScroller@6e7e3f1,android.view.ContextThemeWrapper@7b07080
    D/HwSplineOverScrollerExImpl: initSplineOverScrollerImpl: mScrollerVelocity is 0, value is 0
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabledhttps://******.com/******I/api/device/details/12345678 (295ms)
    D/OkHttp: Cache-Control: no-cache
    D/OkHttp: Pragma: no-cache
    D/OkHttp: Content-Length: 201
    D/OkHttp: Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
    D/OkHttp: Expires: -1
    D/OkHttp: Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
    D/OkHttp: X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
    D/OkHttp: X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
    D/OkHttp: Date: Wed, 05 Feb 2020 16:30:55 GMT
    D/OkHttp: [{"DeviceSerialNumber":"321","Allocated":"","ProductID":"1"}]
    D/OkHttp: <-- END HTTP (201-byte body)
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 104 ms
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 113 ms
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 159 ms
    I/Choreographer: Skipped 2201 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=36717ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=25953684181735, Vsync=25990367513601, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=25990383801242, AnimationStart=25990383985096, PerformTraversalsStart=25990386659054, DrawStart=25990387214262, SyncQueued=25990389656971, SyncStart=25990389901762, IssueDrawCommandsStart=25990390053846, SwapBuffers=25990400487700, FrameCompleted=25990402086137, DequeueBufferDuration=3998000, QueueBufferDuration=648000, 
    I/HiTouch_HiTouchSensor: enabledInPad = false,isPcCastMode = false
    D/HiTouch_PressGestureDetector: onAttached, package=**.***.****, windowType=2, mHiTouchRestricted=false
    I/OpenGLRenderer: Davey! duration=36739ms; Flags=0, IntendedVsync=25953684181735, Vsync=25990367513601, OldestInputEvent=9223372036854775807, NewestInputEvent=0, HandleInputStart=25990383801242, AnimationStart=25990383985096, PerformTraversalsStart=25990386659054, DrawStart=25990412849158, SyncQueued=25990415849679, SyncStart=25990416158533, IssueDrawCommandsStart=25990416515304, SwapBuffers=25990420740304, FrameCompleted=25990424410096, DequeueBufferDuration=419000, QueueBufferDuration=683000, 
    D/mali_winsys: EGLint new_window_surface(egl_winsys_display *, void *, EGLSurface, EGLConfig, egl_winsys_surface **, EGLBoolean) returns 0x3000
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 177 ms
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 141 ms
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 177 ms
    W/libEGL: EGLNativeWindowType 0x7e03547010 disconnect failed
    D/OpenGLRenderer:   HWUI Binary is  enabled
    E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 266 ms
```

Please help, I am new to android.

All activities, keyboards, and all services are running very slow in Huawei phones.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: can u share complete log?

Comment: I have edited my question, please find the logcat in it

Comment: E/IPCThreadState: binder thread pool (15 threads) starved for 266 ms 
this error is been repeated over continuously and once this error occurs the app freezes and becomes very slow

Answer (score 0):

There are many reasons why some Android software can't run on Huawei mobile phones. Although Huawei's mobile phone now uses Android system, it's a deeply customized Android. Many of the underlying codes have been changed. It's also a common phenomenon that some of the less popular applications can't run.

When an application cannot run on Huawei mobile phones, it is necessary to determine whether the application is caused by the system version. Due to the relatively fast update of Android system, the system code will change after each major version upgrade. So some old version applications may not be able to run in the new version system. Even some apps that can run normally on Android 9 cannot be opened normally on Android 10. The flagship products of Huawei's mobile phones will basically be equipped with the latest Android system. For example, Huawei mate 30 Pro is equipped with Android 10. If the system version is too new and the application version is too old, the two are not compatible.

The solution to this problem is very simple, that is to download the latest version of the application. As long as the general application is upgraded and maintained normally, it can adapt to the new system soon. If an app is left unattended for a long time and the version is too low, Android phones of Huawei and other brands may not work properly.

The second situation is that the cracked version of the application is difficult to run on Huawei mobile phones. This is because the security management of Huawei's emui system is strict. It will compare the characteristic data of the installed application with the cloud data. The characteristic data of the cracked application is definitely different from that of the genuine application, so it can't be recognized by Huawei's system and can't be installed naturally. The main solution to this problem is to click the pinion in the upper right corner of the mobile manager, and then turn off the "intelligent maintenance" option. However, some Huawei mobile phone users said that even if this function was turned off, most of the cracked applications could not be installed.

The third situation is some software that needs Google service framework to run normally, such as Gmail, Google maps, etc., because these applications all rely on Google GMS services and cannot run independently. Because Huawei is blocked by Google, it is difficult for the new Huawei mobile phone to install Google GMS service. However, there are also some tutorials on the network, which can be searched by users in need.

In general, there are many reasons why some Android software can't run on Huawei mobile phones. When Huawei mobile users use applications, it is better to download and install them from Huawei's own app store, so that they have the least chance of problems and are relatively safer.